# Splitting Frame border into two segments

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-maui

I am using MAUI with Visual Studio 2022 Preview 17.3.0

I am trying to create a border that resembles the image below:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQFdA.png)

I'm not sure how possible this is, I've had a look around but haven't found anything so far, I've also tried playing with it to no avail.

Comment: do you mean the thicker border on the bottom and right?  That is called a "drop shadow"

Comment: @Jason My apologies - would you know how to apply a drop shadow to a frame and/or button?

Comment: set `HasShadow = true`